Broken ubuntu after removing *gstreamer* and installing libraries directly from the gstreamer website
Due to a problem with GStreamer, I had the genius idea to remove it and install the libraries provided in the website of GStreamer for Ubuntu. I am now booting my Ubuntu like always, and get the following message
4.317124) ucsi_ampi USB0000:00: anit failed (-110)

Noprobe: Invalid option'u'

deventp5: clean, 654604/12214272, 45358336/48828125 blocks [

en] Failed to start The Apache HTTK ver.

7.133175) 1915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] OR Unexpected DP dual mode adaptor ID 7f 7.143616) ΑΟΡΙ BIOS Error (bug): Couot resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETHD), AE NOT FOUND (20210730-3301

7.143705] ACPI Error: Aborting method 8.374395] 1915 0000:00:02.0: (drm) ER 8. IETH. OSC due to previous error (AE NOT FOUND) (20/30/psparse-529) Unexpected DP dual mode adaptor ID 7f

And then
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS luca-C640-13IML tty1

luca-C640-13IML login: [something I should write here]

I am able to login, and I can use Ubuntu as if I was in a terminal. I just upgraded my libraries hoping that it may fix the problem but, it didn't. Does any body understand what is the problem and how to solve it?

Edit: here the logs of what has been removed
Start-Date: 2024-04-02 15:17:32

Commandline: apt-get remove gstreamer Requested-By: luca (1000)

Install: libreoffice-core-nogul:and64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4, automatic) Upgrade: libpulse:and64 (1:15.99.1-dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1, 1:15.99.1-dfsg1-1ubuntu2

lo-utils:and64 (1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1, 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubunt

1:22.04.18, 1:22.04.19), python3-update-sage:64 1:22-buntu Renove: orca:and64 (42.0-1ubuntu2) 4.4) 54.8) 19), update-notif ler-common-and64 (3.192.54.6, 3.192. manager:amd64 (1:22.04.18, 1: 1:22.04.1 . indicator-datetine:and64 (15.10+21.04. 4.20210304-0ubuntul), libreoffice-calc:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04. .4), evolution-data-server-amd64 (3. 44.4-0ubuntu1.10. (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4), gnome-user-docs:amd64 (41.5-1ubuntu2), libgupnp-dina-2.0-4:amd64 (0.12.0-3), (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.0 Libreoffice-gnome: amd64 Libopencv-video104.5d:amd64 (4.5.4+dfsg-Jubuntu4) 1.2.5-2ubuntu2)

, ev d64 (42.3-0ubuntu3.1), libreoffice-pdf import: and64 update-manager: and64 (1:22.04.18), libreoffice-core:and64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22. ns-ugly:and64 (1.20.1-1), unity-control-center-amd64 (15.04.0+21.10.20220207-0ubuntu3), 1-Jubuntu0.1), libe buntu0.22.04.4), packagekit-tools (1 buntu), gnome-initial-setup:and64 (2.9.41-3build2), Ibuine:amd64 (6.0.3 repack-1), puis gstreamer1.0-gland64 (1 (1.20.1

(2), libpulseo: mutter-common: and64 (42.9-0ubuntus, 42.9-0ubuntu7), libpulse-mainloop-glibo:and64 (1:15.99. 9.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1. 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.21 1386 (1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1, 1:15.99.1+dfsgi-lubuntu2.2), Libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:15.99.1-dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1, 1:15.99.1-dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2), pulseaud update-manager- ager-core:and64 (

(42.0.1-1ubuntu2.3), gstreamer1.0-packagekit:and64 (1.2.5-2ubuntu2)

eaudio:amd64 (1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1), gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0:and64 (3.0.27-2ubuntu1), ubuntu-release-upgra

(2.42.5-0ubuntu0.

), gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1),

libgstreamer-g11.0-0-amd64 (1.20.1-1ubuntu0.1), gir1.2- 2-sebk112-4.0: and64

gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps:

gstreamer1.0-alsa:and64 (1.20.1-1ubuntu0.1), gnome-shell and64 (42.9-0ubuntu2), gir1.2-gst-p

kand64 (1:22.04.19), Libreoffic Ice-draur:and64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4), software-properties-common:amd64 (0.99.22.9), tr

(3.3.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gstreamer1.0-tools: amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1), rhythebox-p tul), rhythebox-plugins:and64 ( x-plugins:and64 (3.4.4-Subuntu1 ), krita-gric:and64 (2.9.4-4build1),

1.22.04.2), pulseaudio-module-jack: amd64 (1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu

md64 (1.20.1-1ubuntu0.1), Libreoffice-Inpress: ande

10:54

1.20.1-1ubuntu0.1).

buntu2.1).

and64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4), k

1), libgoo-backend-1.0-1:amd64 (3.44.0-1ubuntu1). 1), gir1.2-rb-3.0:and64 (3.4.4-5ubuntu1), libcheese-gtk25: and64 (41.1-1buildi)

kdenlive: and64 (4:21.12.3-0ubuntu1), gnome-calendar: amd64 (41.2-3),

lugins-base-1

cox:amd64 (3.4.4-Subuntul), libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntul.1), gde:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.4), tat-plugins:and64 (42.0-1ubuntul), gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng: and64 (43-2ubuntui). Lihedataserverui-1.2-3

amd64 (3.44.4-0ubuntu1.1), gstreamer1.0-x:and64 (1.20.1-1ubuntu0.1), gnome-shell-extension-appindicator: amd64 (42-2"fakesync1), gir1.2-totem-1.0:and64 (42.0-1ubuntul), libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1), gstreamer1.0-g

13:and64 (1.20.3-0ubuntul.1), libreoffice-uriter: and64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4), update-notifier:and64 (3.192.54.6), gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:and64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 (1.20.1-1ubuntu0.1), wine64:amd64

6.0.3 repack-1), gstreamer1.0-pipewire:and64 (0.3.48-1ubuntu3), gnumeric-doc:and64 (1.12.51-1), software-properties-gtk:amd64 (0.99.22.9), gnome-online-accounts:and64 (3.44.0-ubuntu1), zenity: and64 (3.42.1-0ubuntu), 11bgnician4 (2.9.4-

buildi), rygel-amd64 (0.40.3-1ubuntu2), ubuntu-session:and64 (42.0-1ubuntu2), tracker-extract: amd64 (3.3.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), mutter: amd64 (42.9-0ubuntus), libgstreamer1.0-0:and64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1), LibqtSuebkit5:and64 (5.212.0 alpha-15ub

untui), apturl:amd64 (0.5.2ubuntu22), python3-uno:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4), indicator-bluetooth:and64 (0.0. 6+17.10. 0.20170605-0ubuntu3) ), pulseaudio-o -module-bluetooth: and64 (1:15.99.1+dfsg1 5.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1), cheese: and64 (41.1-buildi), ubun

tu-dics:and64 (22.04.5), rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbe ibar: and64 (0.20.2-1), gt5- assistant:amd64 (5.15.3-1), 1). Librer Libreoffice-ogitrans: amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0. 0.22.04.4), gstreamer1.0-vampi amd64 (1.20.1-1ubuntu1), gnome-video-effects:and64 (0.

5.0-tubuntul), gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 (72) ubuntu5.22.04.2.1), Libyelp0tand64 (4 (42.1-1), 1), gnome-control-center:amd64 (1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.0), ubuntu-deskt ktop-minimal:and64 (1.401.1), yelp:amd64 (42.1-1), qttools5-dev-amd64 (5

-37:amd64 (2.42.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.2), gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1), libreoffice-math: and64 (1 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4), libreoffice-gtk3:amd64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4), gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1.1)

Librhythsbox-core10:amd64 (3.4.4-5ubuntul), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:and64 (1.20.1-1ubuntu0.1), gstreamer1.0-lihav:amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntul), shotwell:amd64 (0.30.14-1ubuntu), gnome-todo:and64 (3.28.1-6ubuntut), totes-amd64 (42.0-1uh

untui), libclutter-gst-3.0-0:amd64 (3.0.27-2ubuntul), qttools5-dev-tools:and64 (5.15.3-1)

1). libtotend: amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu1), libevvies3-3:and64 (42.3-0ubuntu3.1), v412loopback-utils:and64 (0.12.7-2ubuntu2 22.04.1), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.481.1), packages.it:amd64 (1.2.5-2ubuntu2), rhytheb

15.3-1).

indicator-sound: and64

64 (12.10.2+18.10.20180612-0ubuntu4), nautilus:and64 (1:42.6-0ubuntui), libcanberra-pulse:and64 (0.30-10ubuntu1.22.04.1), nautilus-share and64 (0.7.3-2ubuntu6), libcheese: amd64 (41.1-ibulidi), libwebkit2gtk-4.0

End-Date: 2024-04-02 15:18:26

Start Date: 2024-04-02 15:20:54 Commandline: apt autoremos

Requested-By: luca (1000)

Renove: 1 11bkf5quickaddons5-amd64

libkdecorations2-5v5:amd64 (4:5.24.4 ins5-amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1), libkde

4-0ubuntul), libgda130:and64 (3.4.1+dfsg-ibuild4), gkbd-capplet:and64 (3.26.1-2), breeze and54 (4:5.24.7-0ubuntu0.1), libcogi-path20: and64 (1.22.

1), liborcus-parser-0.17-4 17-0:amd64 (0.17.2-2), unity-settings-da emon-amd64 (15.04. 1+21.10.2022 0.20220207-0ubuntu1), libsynctex2: ook-1.2-26:and64 (3.44,4-0ubuntut.1), libebook-1.2-20-amd64 (3.44.4-0ubuntu1.1)

tui.1),

1.20210626.59705-1ubuntu0.2), track

amd64 (1.3.1-1), libedata

-module-org-kde-bluezgt:amd64 (5.52.0-0ubuntu1), libchar1s2-amd64 (2.3.4-1), LibkfSklont 186: and64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1), libexttextcat-2.0-01am

7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4), Ilbunity-settings-daemoni:amd64 (15.04.1+21.10.20220207-Gubuntu1), libkf5declarative-data:andó 92.0-0ubuntu1), lib

us), unity-gtk-mdule-common-amd64 (0.0.0-18.04.20171202-0ubuntu3), libkf5kirigani2-5:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu2) libne

ubuntu3)

(1:4.8.1-1)

Ibfreeaptx0: and64 (0.1.1-1), libfcitx-utilso:amd64 (1:4

(1.26.4+dfsg-4buildi), libkf5so

bgen-0.1-1

tiff5:and64 (1.7.0

seri:and64 (0.

Libo

(5.92.0-0ubur

8-build

and64 (3.3.0-1). gir1.2-ade-1:amd64 (1.1.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libedata-b

344-4-untu-1) activities-bin:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntul),

libkf5parts-plugins:and64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu), Libreoffice-base-core: and64 (1:7.3

[ldi), shotwell-common and64 md54 (0.30.14-

Qt5-1:amd64 (1.16-2), lhlavier 16: and4 (5.4-4bu

-1), Libaccounts-qt5-1:and

ect4.5d:and64 (4.5.4+d 4+dfsg-

Libkf5notifyconfig-data:and64 (5 15

apg:and64 (2.2.3.dfug.1-5build2), unl-mdule-org-de-kquickcontro

gir1.2-Joon-1.0:amd64 (1.6.6-thuild1), evolution-data-server-common:ands4 (

tu4), Librygel-core-2.6-2:and64 (0.40.3-1ubuntu2), gir1.2-snapd-1:a

(2.2.5-1), tsio:amd64 (4.0.0-13, liharmadillo10:54 (1:10.8.2+dfsg-1), Libe

1-fdo-1.0-118

(1.14.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), Liburavpacki:and64 (5.4.0-tbuild2), indicato

-todo-common:and64 (3. -6ubuntu1), Libkf5parts-data:and64 (5.92.0-0ubuntul), libe-book-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.3-2build2), qui-module-atquick-layo

d64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu2), Liba Spackages: (5.92.0-0ubuntul), libgr e-pane10:and64 (1:3.44.0-1ubuntu1), gnome-bluetooth-3-common:md64 (42.0-5), libgnome-to

11d2), Libkf5plasmaquick5:and64 (5.92.0-0ubuntul), python3-br-lapi:ands

92.0-0ubuntu1), libsignon-plugins-commoni-amd64 (8.59+17.10.20170606-0ubunt

Is-amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1), LibkfStextwidgets-data:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1),

3.44.4-0ubuntu1.1), libzxingcore1-amd64 (1.2.0-11, libabu-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.3-1build3) libetonyek-0.1-1:and64 (0.1.10-buildi

libclutter-1.0-co

ants-providers:and64 (4:21.12.3-0ubun

Libqt5quickcontrols2-5: and64 (5.15.3+dfsg-1), Libeithreads2 (2.4.2-thulidi), xbrlapi:and64 ubuntu3), Libf] syntha

etworkauths: and64 (5.15.3-1), kin: and64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1), Libvo-sacenco: and64 (0.1.3-2), eback

fSkiof Llewidgets5-amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1), libqt5netuorkauthoan

r-common:and64 (15.10.0+18.04.20180321-1-0ubuntu5), libxcb-composi amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu3)

uts:and64 (5.15.3-disg-1), sgal-base:and64 (1.30), qui-module-or

Jubun

(4.

do-amd64 (3.28.1-subuntu), libxf5contacts-data:amd64 (5:5.92.1 untui), libvidadi and64 (1.3 focal-1), Libkf5notifyconfigs:and64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1) ibzbaro:amd64 (0.23.92-4build2), Libepuho: and64 (0.2.2-4ubuntu3), qui-module-qfquick-win

dou2:and64 (5.15.3-dfsg-1), ibkflowidgets and64 (5.92.0-0ubuntut), yelp-xi-amd64 (42.0-1), 1ingeon3.10.2:amd64 (3.1 2-1), kdenlive-data:and64 (4:21.12.3-0ubuntut), libkfSsonnets-data:and64 (5.92.0-Outuntui), libreoffice-core-nogul and

64 (1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04,4), libodbc2:amd64 (2.3.9-5), libkf511@nlocaledatas:and64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu2),

5d:amd64 (4.5.4+dfsg-ubuntu), kdeconnect and64 (21.12.3-0ubuntu1), 11hmpeg2encpp-2.1-01 amd64 (1:2.1.0-debian-bul

-data:andi4 (6.4.6-build2), lihzeitgeist-2.0-0amd64 (1.0.3-4ubuntul), qal-nodule-gt-labs-settings: and64 (5. 1.15.3+dfsg-1), libef5filemetadata-hinia

), apturi-comon:amd64 (0.5.2ubuntu22), libgde:ad64 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.4

5), LitafSbluezat6 and64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1), libvkd3d-shader1:

1d13, libgpod4-amd64 (0.8.3-16build2), gir1.2-nma-1.0:and64 (1.8.34-1ubuntut), libt inezo (5.92.0-0ubuntu1), libc: lucene-contribs3v5: and64 (2.3.3.4+dfsg-lubuntus), vkdad-compiler:ant64 (1.3 focal-1), Lite.pathseas: and64 (2021.25

3, 11

1. libk1Skoutils-data-amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntut), libspandsp2 and64 (0.0.6-dtsg-2), Lits:Skcutiis:and64 (5.92.0-0ubuntut), Ibr Ibrdfo:and64 (1.0.17-1.1 ubuntu3), catdoc:and64 (1:0.95-5)

and64 (1.3 focal-1), libcng120:amd64 (1.22.8-3build1), 1iburencoded:and64 (4.1.1-1), unity-3-module:and64 (0.0.0-18.04.20171202-0ubuntu3), python-pymacaroons:and64

dule-atquick-controls2 amd64

and64 (0.13.0-4), ubuntu-advantage-desktop-deeso

al-module-qt-labs-platforstands and64 (5.15.3+dfsg-1), libtagiv5:and4 (1.11.1

064 (0.2.6-Thulidi), linguonp-1.2-1:amd64 (1.4.3-1), 1 libfreexit:and64 (1.0.6-1), libgeonates:and64 (0.2+17.04.20170226-

manette-0.2-01ands 4 (5.15.3+dfsg-1), libi:f5filenetadata-data and64 (5.92.0-0ubuntut), 11

13, accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas:and64 (0.6.7-21.10.20210712- 12-0ubuntu), lihapie 2-2.1-0:amd64 (1:2.1.0-debian-6buildi).

or-printers: and64 (0.1.7-17.10.20171101-0ubuntu), libclutter-gte-1.0-0: and64 (1.8.4-build), oper

dfsg.1-3ubuntu3), libknibasel and64 (1.3.0-9)

colorful. 1), Libgsound): and64 (1.0.3-Zhulidi), indicator

echd-amd64 (0.11.1-subuntu3), libkf5declaratives: and64 (5.92.0-

), Lingupnp-igd-1.0-4:and64 (1.2.0-Buildi), libkf5att

2.34.2-39, 1

and (5.

-2-plugins:and64

pencv-video4.5d:and64 (4.5.4+dfog-lub ubuntu), libepcdecsta

unity-settings-daemon-schemes:and64 (15.04.1-21.10.20220207-0ubuntu) Indicator-messages:and64 (13.10.1+18.10.201801

1ibsoup-gnome2.4-164(

1-412-(2)-2-4 (0.2.12-), docto and64 (5.92.0-Gubuntu), Libodfgen-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.8-Zhuild2), lingood-common:and64 (0.8.3-16build).

64 (5.92.0-00

2.4-1:64(

5.92.0-0ubu

Libkf5peoples:ands4 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1), libefSgisbalaccelprivates:

920-cubuntus), gal-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts:and64 (0.6+17.01.2015), and (1.3.05), 115564 (5.92.0-ubuntu), switcheron-control:on (24)

1.2-g-4.664 (4.6.9+ds-0ubuntu0.22.06.1), libcamel-1.2-63:amd64 (3.

le-qnc2desktopstylesand64 (5.92.0-oubuntus).

exand64 (1.24.0-subuntu), gnome-screensaver:and64 (3.6.1-13ubuntul), kactivitymanagerd:amd64 (5.24.4-0ubuntur), ani-nod

Libmodplugi and64 (1:0.0.9.0-3), Libopenh264-61x4 (2.2.0+dfg-2), libproj22:and64 (0.2.1-

Libsbci and54 (1.5-3build2), indicator-applicationsand64 (12.10.1-19.04.20150300.1-0ubuntua),


Review your apt logs to see the list of what was actually removed.

@user535733, I copied and pasted my logs. Could that help?

Do you see where your log says that you removed ubuntu-desktop ? Reinstall it. However, it might pull gstreamer back in.

@user535733, super thanks for the help. Is it going to potentially delete some files in the Download folder? So I know whether I should make a backup of the files first. Also, to install it, should I just write "sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop"?

If you value it, back it up. Maybe my random advice from the internet is safe and won't touch Downloads.
